# init or numberWith* for NSNumber using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization, nsnumber

I am comparing NSNumber initWith* methods with numberWith* methods specifically under ARC.
I have the feeling that they are now identical.

```
{
    NSNumber* myInitNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:55];
    NSNumber* myNumbNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:55];
    // use here
}
```

At the final brace, both pointers go out of scope so both reference counts drop to zero and are deallocated.

If they are identical, is there a preference which one I should use?

Comment: You can use this too: `NSNumber *fortyTwo = @42; // equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]`

Comment: They are identical, there is no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:42]
```

It's the same, since it's autoreleased under non-ARC projects. But this has no effect to ARC enabled projects.

Comment: So is there a preference given in any documentation anywhere? Will one be deprecated at some time?

Comment: I don't think so, I use numberWithInt: the whole time because it's smaller code. Unless ARC does not become required for programming apps it will be supported (I think)

Comment: In Xcode 4.4 you can use NSNumber *theAnswerToEverything = @42; to make an NSNumber object.